# Apply a plugin's method to dynamically created elements?

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I'm using the jquery.maskedinput plugin to create a mask for a phone number field:

```
jQuery('input[type="tel"]').mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

Using a modification of Ryan Bates's [nested form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), I have a form where multiple phone numbers can be added dynamically via an "Add phone number" link. This link creates additional inputs, but the mask functionality is not applied. I am aware of the live() method in jQuery but am not sure if/how it can be used to apply the mask() method. Is there a way to apply this mask to dynamically created inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question... I used the [jquery.livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) plugin to do the following:

```
$('input[type="tel"]').livequery(function() {
  $(this).mask("(999) 999-9?999");
});
```